# Display document of CouchDB in JSON format

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I need to get the documents as JSON

The view looks like below

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc._id); 
}
```

The design document looks like below

```
  {
  "_id": "_design/rtls",
  "_rev": "14-cad60060017c38957f6e4388cb37914b",
  "views": {
    "rtls": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit(doc._id);\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

When I get the below data for the below link `http://127.0.0.1:5984/rtls/_design/rtls/_view/rtls?include_docs=true

```
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1",
"key":"1",
"value":null,
"doc":{
    "_id":"1",
    "_rev":"39-6ff9597a13572e831728c2e2631eb425",
    "al":[{
         "id16":"0x3f1a",
         "pos":{"x":17.49,"y":10.97,"z":0.01}}],,
"tl":[],
"Timestamp":272179.0,
"Oid":"apoorva-VirtualBox",
"resultTime":"2021-01-03T23:02:29.059Z"}
 }
........
]}
```

but I need it in the below format

```
[
{"id":"1",
"key":"1",
"value":null,
"_id":"1",
"_rev":"39",
"al":[{
      "id16":"0x3f1a",
      "pos":{"x":17.49,"y":10.97,"z":0.01}}],
"tl":[],
"Timestamp":272179.0,
"Oid":"apoorva-VirtualBox",
"resultTime":"2021-01-03T23:02:29.059Z"
}
]
```

I am very much new to CouchDB. Any input is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The view creates an index that exactly matches the main index exposed by the [_all_docs endpoint](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs). Why? In addition, why *must* the output be in the format you need? Have you no control over client processing?

Comment: Because I have named everything the same I guess. I have to read the JSON in Vue.js. if I could get the view to give the data in the JSON format it would be the whole process would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB offers [list functions](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/ddocs.html#list-functions) to transform view results. As you can see in the doc these functions are deprecated in CouchDB 3.x and will be removed in 4.x. You can solve a need in the short-term but it is better to not rely on it in the long-term

try to define a list function in your design doc like this one ("lists" element):

```
   {
  "_id": "_design/rtls",
   "views": {
    "rtls": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit(doc._id, 1);\n}"
    }
  },
  "lists": {
    "doc-list": "function (head,req) { start({'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});  var row; var docs=[]; while (row = getRow()) {docs.push(row.doc)}; send(toJSON(docs));  }"
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

and query the db with this operation

```
/db/_design/rtls/_list/doc-list/rtls?include_docs=true
```

As this is being deprecated it is better to put this logic on your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not able to use the above design doc. I am getting the error "Document update conflict".

Comment: Is the _rev attribute, you must update your revision. I removed the _rev from my example.